# Why is it recommended to install a 32 bit server on a 64 bit machine

Tags: mysql, apache, server

I was wondering to install a server on my windows machine and came to know that it is best to install a 32bit version on a 64bit machine. Is it really required.
Why is it recommended?
I want to install it for study.

Comment: This should really be on https://serverfault.com/ in my opinion.

Comment: Please add the link to such recommendation.

Comment: here is the video in which I came to know:
https://youtu.be/xeLmHI3GJs8?t=171

Comment: There doesn't seem to be an option to move the question to serverfault. You can only close or delete this question and re-ask it on serverfault. But I posted an answer below, if that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Installing 32-bit software on a 64-bit machine is *not* recommended. No one with any credibility would make this senseless recommendation.

A major disadvantage of 32-bit software is that it cannot use more than 4GB of RAM, because memory addresses must fit into the word size of the software. This is a serious deficiency for a database server, which benefits from extra RAM.

I did consulting for a major company who was having database performance trouble. They were using Windows Server. They had been adding extra RAM DIMMs, having heard that RAM can be used to increase caching resources, but no matter how much RAM they added, it didn't help.

I logged into their site and found they were using Windows Server *32-bit*. They had been spending a ton of money on RAM, but their operating system could not see it.

I listened to the YouTube video you linked to, to hear the justification of the speaker. He seems to be saying that since Windows 64-bit is backward-compatible and can run 32-bit binaries, but the reverse is not true (Windows 32-bit cannot run 64-bit binaries), he thinks you should use 32-bit binaries because they will work on both architectures.

That's bad advice.

The better advice is: **Make sure you aren't using Windows 32-bit.**

Come on, it's 2018. The days of 32-bit platforms is long gone.

Comment: Why is it bad advice to _"use 32-bit binaries because they will work on both architectures"_? Is it bad if I prepare my own local server with only 32-bit binary PHP and Apache to be used by users with both 32 and 64-bit Windows?

Comment: @stckvrw The 64-bit app will use more memory, but typically has better performance than the same app compiled for 32-bit. This varies by app of course, but there are more CPU registers on 64-bit, so there's a chance the app could benefit from them and gain performance.

Answer (score 1):

It is definitely not required.  I would say that it's not even recommended.  Any 64 bit machine will be able to run a 32 bit server, however, a 32 bit server will highly underutilize the processor, especially when performing complex or graphical operations